# how to make working Captcha post comment form?

Tags: javascript

how to make function, when Captcha are correct sumbit by user, than "Post Comment Button" accept the click and post comment..

when captcha are incorrect sumbit by user, than "Post Comment Button" not accept click and says "please fill correct captcha"..

This Is Comment form

```
  <p class="form-submit"><input name="submit" type="submit" 
   id="submit" class="submit" value="Post Comment">
  </p>
```

---

This Is Working Captcha Javascript Code

```js
var code;
function createCaptcha() {
  //clear the contents of captcha div first 
  document.getElementById('captcha').innerHTML = "";
  var charsArray =
  "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@!#$%^&*";
  var lengthOtp = 6;
  var captcha = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lengthOtp; i++) {
    //below code will not allow Repetition of Characters
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * charsArray.length + 1); //get the next character from the array
    if (captcha.indexOf(charsArray[index]) == -1)
      captcha.push(charsArray[index]);
    else i--;
  }
  var canv = document.createElement("canvas");
  canv.id = "captcha";
  canv.width = 100;
  canv.height = 50;
  var ctx = canv.getContext("2d");
  ctx.font = "25px Georgia";
  ctx.strokeText(captcha.join(""), 0, 30);
  //storing captcha so that can validate you can save it somewhere else according to your specific requirements
  code = captcha.join("");
  document.getElementById("captcha").appendChild(canv); // adds the canvas to the body element
}
function validateCaptcha() {
  event.preventDefault();
  debugger
  if (document.getElementById("cpatchaTextBox").value == code) {
    alert("Valid Captcha")
  }else{
    alert("Invalid Captcha. try Again");
    createCaptcha();
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=text] {
    padding: 12px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
button{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 36px;
}
canvas{
  /*prevent interaction with the canvas*/
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<body onload="createCaptcha()">
  <form onsubmit="validateCaptcha()">
    <div id="captcha">
    </div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Captcha" id="cpatchaTextBox"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>



<p class="form-submit"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Post Comment"> <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="11666" id="comment_post_ID">
<input type="hidden" name="comment_parent" id="comment_parent" value="0">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your question has answer inside it

```
function validateCaptcha() {
    if (document.getElementById("cpatchaTextBox").value == code) {
        alert("Valid Captcha")
        // Here add whatever you want to do if captcha is correct
    }
    else {
        alert("Invalid Captcha. try Again");
        createCaptcha();
        // And if captcha is incorrect than here it will show and alert on top and then it will make captcha once again
    }
}
```

Just see this code and read the Comments!